# Setting index and plotting at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a simple linegraph using one column as an index and another as a column using Jupyter notebook. I tried:

```
dataframe.set_index('Year'),['AUD'].plot()
```

which results in a `'list' object has no attribute 'plot'` error.

I can create a new dataframe with `Year` as an index and than plot `AUD`, but can I get some help on simply plotting in one line?

Comment: you have a syntax error, remove coma: `dataframe.set_index('Year'),['AUD'].plot()` --> `dataframe.set_index('Year')['AUD'].plot()`

Comment: Thanks heaps!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[101,102,103,104],'aud':[34,45,46,67]})
df.set_index('year')['aud'].plot()
```